# opening a variable in php from a text file

Tags: php

i want to copy some files the hard way (dont ask me why its just too complicated) and use a variable created to a file and opened from another script then it initiates the coping

i already made a functional page that saves the value i want now i have this code that i want to extract the variable that is in a file called tmpCraft.txt and make it copy the specified file to the destination from the tmp file so this is my code its called accountCrafter.php

```
<?php

$dst = fopen("tmpCraft.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");   
echo fread($dst,filesize("tmpCraft.txt"));  
fclose($dst);

$file = 'structure/index.html';

if (!copy($file, $dst . "/index.html")) {
    echo "failed to copy $file...\n"; 
}else{
    echo "copied $file into $newfile\n"; 
}

?>
```

i ran it and this was the result:

> noni
>   Warning: copy(Resource id #3/index.html) [function.copy]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in H:\xampp\htdocs\dev4\test2\accountCrafter.php on line 9
>   failed to copy structure/index.html...

The value was `noni`

for some reason it extracts the value as

Comment: What do you expect `$dst . "/index.html"` to do? `$dst` is a file handle, not a string containing a directory name.

Comment: `$dst` was a file pointer, not a string. Correct the directory that you're passing into the copy function.

Comment: "extracts the value as" what?

Comment: Are you trying to copy `structure/index.html` to `noni/index.html`?

Comment: Instead of `echo`ing the result of the `fread`, put it in a variable and use that in the `copy` instead of `dst`.

Comment: i figured it out i could have just used $dst = file(File path)

Comment: yes exactly barmar that was what i was trying to do

Comment: thanks a lot barmar

Comment: the value of Resource id #3/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you want:

```
<?php
$dst = trim(file_get_contents("tmpCraft.txt"));
$file = 'structure/index.html';
$newfile = $dst . "/index.html";

if (!copy($file, $newfile)) {
    echo "failed to copy $file...\n"; 
}else{
    echo "copied $file into $newfile\n"; 
}

?>
```

You need to set `$dst` to the contents of the file, not the file handle. `trim()` will remove any extraneous whitespace around the name in the file.

Comment: this is what i get 
Warning: copy(noni /index.html) [function.copy]: failed to open stream: Invalid argument in H:\xampp\htdocs\dev4\test2\accountCrafter.php on line 6
failed to copy structure/index.html...

Comment: Looks like your file has a space after the name. Use `trim()` to remove extra whitespace.

Comment: i see what is happening i added to $newfile in the failed section of your code and i saw a space between the value dst and / index.html so this is exactly what i mean

Comment: failed to copy structure/index.html... to noni /index.html

Comment: you can see a space between noni and /index